# Backquote Expanding a Series of Elements in a List

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Let's say I have a struct (which has more parameters than shown here):

```
(defstruct location
  name)
```

And an association list defining a series of locations using the backquote:

```
(defparameter *locations* `(
  (ASIA ,(make-location :name "Asia"))
  (AFRICA ,(make-location :name "Africa"))
  )
```

This works fine and correctly creates the location structs. The problem is, I'm planning on having a lot of locations, more than would be nice to type out all by hand:

```
(defparameter *locations* `(
  (ASIA ,(make-location :name "Asia"))
  (AFRICA ,(make-location :name "Africa"))
  (LOC1 ,(make-location :name "Location 1"))
  ; Lots more...
  (LOC1024 ,(make-location :name "Location 1027"))
  )
```

A lot of these extra locations have similar parameters, such that I can define a "generator function" to create a list of them:

```
(defun generate-locations (symbol name count)
  (loop for i from 1 to count collect (list
    (read-from-string (format nil "~A~D" symbol i))
    (make-location :name name))))

;;; Creates list ((LOC1 #S(LOCATION :NAME "Location 1")) (LOC2 ...
(generate-locations "LOC" "Location " 1024)
```

So then I tried to do something like:

```
(defparameter *locations* `(
  (ASIA ,(make-location :name "Asia"))
  (AFRICA ,(make-location :name "Africa"))
  ,(generate-locations "LOC" "Location " 1024)
  )
```

Doesn't work, because `GENERATE-LOCATIONS` returns a **list**, not a **series of elements** which can then be *added* to a list. So I tried to `VALUES-LIST` it:

```
(defparameter *locations* `(
  (ASIA ,(make-location :name "Asia"))
  (AFRICA ,(make-location :name "Africa"))
  ,(values-list (generate-locations "LOC" "Location " 1024))
  )
```

This only adds the first generated location to `*LOCATIONS*`. I'm assuming this is because all return values except the first of `VALUES-LIST` are ignored.

So how do I correctly add a series of elements to `*LOCATIONS*`? Should `GENERATE-LOCATIONS` be a macro? And if so, how would it be structured?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the splicing unquote operator, `,@`. In your example:

```
(defparameter *locations* `(
  (ASIA ,(make-location :name "Asia"))
  (AFRICA ,(make-location :name "Africa"))
  ,@(generate-locations "LOC" "Location " 1024)
  )
```

For this to work, `generate-locations` should return a list. `,@` will splice each item into the surrounding list, rather than inserting it as a single item.

Comment: @WilliamGaul You can read more about [backquote in the HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I can't believe I didn't see that page...gotta learn to use the hyperspec more :P Anyway thanks for the resource!

Comment: @WilliamGaul I just included it for the sake of completeness.  Backquote's not too hard to find in the spec, but some of the non-alphanumeric symbols can be difficult to find if you can't, e.g., remember what they call the '#' character.  E.g, searching for hash-sign pipe, you might, if you're lucky, eventually find [sharpsign vertical-bar](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/02_dhs.htm).  At first I thought backquote might be one of those tricky cases, too.